# C2676 Compiling Error while implementing a list of structs

Tags: c++, list, struct, compiler-errors

I am trying to check if there is already an element with same value inside a list of structs so if there isnt I push back to the list a new struct.Consider it like a system with accounts and if there is already an account I dont want to add it on the list again.

Here is my code in main:

```
accounts test;
test.bal = 0;
test.id = 0;
std::list <accounts> accs;
std::list<accounts>::iterator check;
```

Here is my code outside of main:

```
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
struct accounts {
    long id;
    int bal;

};
```

Here is my code inside a for loop:

```
 check = find(accs.begin(), accs.end(), test.id);
        if (check == accs.end()) {
            accs.push_back(test);
        }
```

When I run the code I get a compiler error :

> Error C2676   binary '==': 'accounts' does not define this operator or a
> conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined
> operator  bankacc C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xutility  5440

I have seen other threads and I think I need to do a

```
if(check == accs.id.end())
```

or something like that but it doesnt work, displaying error:

> Error (active)    E0135   class "std::list<accounts,
> std::allocator>" has no member "id"

Any ideas ? :)

Comment: *I think I need to do an somehow* Don't guess, the compiler shows you an exact line.

Comment: @S.M. let me improve my question

Comment: `if(check == accs.id.end())` is not correct or the solution.

Comment: It gets very confusing to read code that use plural nouns for singular things. If a type represents an account, call it "account", not "accounts".

Comment: @molbdnilo when I remove the part inside the for loop the code works and yes I am sorry you are right about the variable names I forgot to change them

Comment: If you look more carefully, you will notice that the message refers to the line with `find`. That's because there is no `==` defined for comparing an `accounts` and a `long`. (The compiler can't know that you wanted to compare to the `id` member.)

Comment: I see the bug is here: `check = find(accs.begin(), accs.end(), test.id);` You are comparing a test.id with an accounts. The compiler won't automatically guess how you want to make this comparison. The find_if() answer should help unless you have no experience with lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple. When you use `std::find`, what happens under the hood is something like this,

```cpp
for(iterator i = begin; i != end; i++)
    if(*i == check) return i;
```

Looking at this, you can see that when we pass in your list, the iterator type is `std::list<accounts>::iterator` but what you check against is `accounts::id`. There isn't a way to do this.

So what are the options? You have 3,

1. Create a `==` operator to the `accounts` struct.
2. Just pass in `test` to test.
3. Pass in a function to do the compare.

The first is simple, you can copy paste this if you want,

```cpp
struct accounts {
    long id;
    int bal;
    
    bool operator==(const long& otherID) const { return id == otherID; }
};
```

Now when `std::find` calls the `==` operator, it knows what to do.

The third is simple, use a lambda.

```cpp
check = find(accs.begin(), accs.end(), [&test](const accounts& other) {
      return other.id == test.id; });
if (check == accs.end()) {
    accs.push_back(test);
}
```

Comment: So both lists should be iterators?

Comment: Sorry i mistakenly posted the wrong answer (half completed). I edited it.

Comment: For the first the error 
`Error C2679 binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion) bankacc C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xutility 5440 ` and for the 3rd it pop ups the same error as before

Comment: @TheCodingGuy I typed `const accounts&` where it should be `const long&`. Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks it fixed the bug but for some reason the struct isnt pushed and is getting numbers it shouldnt probably thats my mistake somewhere thanks though

Answer (score 1):

`std::find` takes an object of the same type as the types in your container that you want to find as the last argument.  In your case, you should use `std::find_if` instead:

```
check = find_if(accs.begin(), accs.end(),
    [&test](const auto& ac) {
      return ac.id == test.id;
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much that worked. Can you please explain what its actually done here after [&test]?(Actually it worked but it didnt push the struct) @johnmastroberti

Comment: The code uses a lambda expression: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: The last argument too `find_if` is a function that should return `true` when the condition you want to find is met. I've accomplished that here with a lambda (the bit from `[&test]` to the ending brace). You can read more about that [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). The code that I posted only replaces your call to `find`. You still need the the last three lines you had, where you push back the new account if it was not found.

Comment: @johnmastroberti ohhh ok thank u very much.I suppose its normal for accs to be size=4456540? Because I put it on watch and thats the size it gives me

Comment: I think you should probably ask a separate question about that.

Comment: ***I suppose its normal for accs to be size*** I agree with @johnmastroberti, ask a new separate question about that and make sure you add a [mcve] as I could not answer with only the information in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Just overload the Operator "==". In the parameters Fetch the desired Type of the value you want.